# I have a sample function and need to know how to work out at any point during the 20 samples being taken does the total ever <0

Tags: r

The code is as follows:

```
run.spinner=10000
spinner.total=rep(0,run.spinner)
for (s in 1:run.spinner){
  spinner.result=sample(c(1,1,-1,2),20,replace=T)
  spinner.count=(sum(spinner.result))
  if (sum(spinner.result<0)){
   spinner.total[s]=0
  }
  spinner.total[s]=spinner.count
}
print(spinner.total)
```

I need to record every time the spinner.result <0 during  the sampling  and if this occurs force a break for that spin and set the spinner.total value to 0. I need to record it as a 0 and if if ever drops below 0 as to model in say a living system where cells might die are a result of a drug being administered.

Comment: You could use the `next()` function in the conditional statement to skip immediately to the next iteration of the loop, but I'd recommend just putting `spinner.total[s]=spinner.count` in an `else` statement, so either one or the other assignment occurs, but not both

Answer (score 0):

This one?

```
run.spinner=10000
 spinner.total=rep(0,run.spinner)
 df<-data.frame()
 for (s in 1:run.spinner){
   spinner.result=sample(c(1,1,-1,2),20,replace=T)
   spinner.count=(sum(spinner.result))
   if(any(spinner.result<0)){
     df[s,1]<-s
     df[s,2]<-0
   }else{
     df[s,1]<-s
     df[s,2]<-spinner.count
   }
 }
 summary(df)
       V1              V2         
 Min.   :    1   Min.   : 0.0000  
 1st Qu.: 2501   1st Qu.: 0.0000  
 Median : 5000   Median : 0.0000  
 Mean   : 5000   Mean   : 0.0768  
 3rd Qu.: 7500   3rd Qu.: 0.0000  
 Max.   :10000   Max.   :30.0000
```